# Retrieving the values of array in table view cell swift ios

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, nsarray

I am trying to retrieve the values of `wInstockArray` in a table view cell. Currently the the `wInstockArray` is empty I am inserting a string on a button click and appending in array. but when I retried the values in `cellForRowAtIndexath` method it gives error

> Index out of range

What I have defined is :

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return wInstockArray.count + 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let firstCell = firstTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "firstCell")! as UITableViewCell
    if wInstockArray.count == 0 {
        print("no widgets in instock")
    } else {
        firstCell.textLabel?.text = wInstockArray[indexPath.row]
        print("\(wInstockArray.count)")  //prints 1
        return firstCell
    }
}
```

inside button click action

```
wInstockArray.append(item)
```

Comment: Please show full code

Comment: updated code.......

Comment: @RajeshKumarR updated

Comment: since you are return wInstockArray.count + 1it will get index out of range . For count +1 you should return empty cell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `numberOfRowsInSection` method return wInstockArray array count

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

  return wInstockArray.count
}
```

Inside the button click action, reload the tableView

```
wInstockArray.append(item)
tableView.reloadData()
```

Comment: it gives error at                 firstCell?.textLabel?.text = wInstockArray[indexPath.row]

Comment: index out of range

Comment: @iOSDeveloper What do you return in numberOfRowsInSection method?

Comment: apologies its fine

Answer (score 1):

Inside button click method, please reload your table.

```
YOUR_TABLE.reloadData()
```

and update this method,

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
     return wInstockArray.count
}
```